# Grep from file fails but grep with individual lines from the file works

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to extract lines from file genome.gff that contain a line from file suspicious.txt. suspicious.txt was derived from genome.gff and every line should match.

Using grep on a single line from suspicious.txt works as expected:

```
grep 'gene10002' genome.gff
NC_007082.3 Gnomon  gene    1269632 1273520 .   +   .   ID=gene10002;Dbxref=BEEBASE:GB54789,GeneID:409846;Name=bur;gbkey=Gene;gene=bur;gene_biotype=protein_coding
NC_007082.3 Gnomon  mRNA    1269632 1273520 .   +   .   ID=rna21310;Parent=gene10002;Dbxref=GeneID:409846,Genbank:XM_393336.5,BEEBASE:GB54789;Name=XM_393336.5;gbkey=mRNA;gene=bur;product=burgundy;transcript_id=XM_393336.5
```

But every variation on using grep from a file that I've been able to think of or find online produces no output or an empty file:

```
grep -f suspicious.txt genome.gff
grep -F -f suspicious.txt genome.gff
while read line; do grep "$line" genome.gff; done<suspicious.txt
while read line; do grep '$line' genome.gff; done<suspicious.txt
while read line; do grep "${line}" genome.gff; done<suspicious.txt
cat suspicious.txt | while read line; do grep '$line' genome.gff; done
cat suspicious.txt | while read line; do grep '$line' genome.gff >> suspicious.gff; done
cat suspicious.txt | while read line; do grep -e "${line}" genome.gff >> suspicious.gff; done
cat "$(cat suspicious_bee_geneIDs_test.txt)" | while read line; do grep -e "${line}" genome.gff >> suspicious.gff; done
```

Running it as a script also produces an empty file:

```
#!/bin/bash
SUSP=$1
GFF=$2

while read -r line; do
        grep -e "${line}" $GFF >> suspicious_bee_genes.gff
done<$SUSP
```

This is what the files look like:

```
head genome.gff
##gff-version 3
#!gff-spec-version 1.21
#!processor NCBI annotwriter
#!genome-build Amel_4.5
#!genome-build-accession NCBI_Assembly:GCF_000002195.4
##sequence-region NC_007070.3 1 29893408
##species http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=7460
NC_007070.3 RefSeq  region  1   29893408    .   +   .       ID=id0;Dbxref=taxon:7460;Name=LG1;gbkey=Src;genome=chromosome;linkage-    group=LG1;mol_type=genomic DNA;strain=DH4
NC_007070.3 Gnomon  gene    181 211962  .   -   .   ID=gene0;Dbxref=BEEBASE:GB42164,GeneID:726912;Name=cort;gbkey=Gene;gene=cort;gene_biotype=protein_coding
NC_007070.3 Gnomon  mRNA    181 71559   .   -   .   ID=rna0;Parent=gene0;Dbxref=GeneID:726912,Genbank:XM_006557348.1,BEEBASE:GB42164;Name=XM_006557348.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=cort;product=cortex%2C transcript variant X2;transcript_id=XM_006557348.1

wc -l genome.gff
457742

head suspicious.txt
gene10002
gene1001
gene1003
gene10038
gene10048
gene10088
gene10132
gene10134
gene10181
gene10209

wc -l suspicious.txt
928
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: In you sample code, none of the suspicious.txt patterns are present in genome.gff. Adding a simple `gene` string in suspicious.txt produce the expected result for me with your script.

Comment: could you add ouput of these cmds? cat -v suspicious.txt | head ; ( tail suspicious.txt ; printf "//end\n" "";)

Comment: could you edit your script? insert a line after line 1: set -x . Then save and run again the script, add the output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when the input file is in DOS format: each line will have a trailing CR character at the end, which will break the matching.

One way to check if this is the case is using `hexdump`, for example (just the first few lines):

> ```
> $ hexdump -C suspicious.txt
> 00000000  67 65 6e 65 31 30 30 30  32 0d 0a 67 65 6e 65 31  |gene10002..gene1|
> 00000010  30 30 31 0d 0a 67 65 6e  65 31 30 30 33 0d 0a 67  |001..gene1003..g|
> 00000020  65 6e 65 31 30 30 33 38  0d 0a 67 65 6e 65 31 30  |ene10038..gene10|
> ```

In the ASCII representation at the right, notice the `..` after each gene. These dots correspond to `0d` and `0a`. The `0d` is the CR character.

Without the CR character, the output should look like this:

> ```
> $ hexdump -C <(tr -d '\r' < suspicious.txt)
> 00000000  67 65 6e 65 31 30 30 30  32 0a 67 65 6e 65 31 30  |gene10002.gene10|
> 00000010  30 31 0a 67 65 6e 65 31  30 30 33 0a 67 65 6e 65  |01.gene1003.gene|
> 00000020  31 30 30 33 38 0a 67 65  6e 65 31 30 30 34 38 0a  |10038.gene10048.|
> ```

Just one `.` after each gene, corresponding to `0a`, and no `0d`.

Another way to see the DOS line endings in the `vi` editor. If you open the file with `vi`, the status line would show `[dos]`, or you could run the ex command `:set ff?` to make it tell you the file format (the status line will say `fileformat=dos`).

You can remove the CR characters on the fly like this:

```
grep -f <(tr -d '\r' < suspicious.txt) genome.gff
```

Or you could remove in `vi`, by running the ex command `:set ff=unix` and then save the file. There are other command line tools too that can remove the DOS line ending.

Another possibility is that instead of a trailing CR character, you might have trailing whitespace. The output of `hexdump -C` should make that perfectly clear. After the trailing whitespace characters are removed, the `grep -f` should work as expected.